# Load url from routes for a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

As **CodeIgniter** comes out of the box, it supportes one controller for each unique url.
So, let's say i have the following urls in my **routes.php** file:

```
$route['default_controller']  = "homepage";
$route['404_override']        = "homepage/not_found";

$route['^products$']          = "product/list";
$route['^product/(:any)$']    = "product/details";
```

My urls will look like this:

1. product list => http://www.mywebsite.com/products
2. product details => http://www.mywebsite.com/product/my-custom-product

In the controller where I build the products list, I create the url for each product like this:

```
$this->db->from('products');
$products_result = $this->db->get();

$data['products'] = array();
foreach ($products_result->result() as $row)
{
    $data['products'][] = array(
        'title' => $row->title,
        'image' => $row->image,
        'url'   => site_url('product/' . $row->url)
    );
}

$this->load->view('products/list_view', $data);
```

But there is too much redundancy for each url. I have to write the url every time I want to echo it somewhere. If I want to change the url, I have to open each php file and replace them all.

**Question:** Isn't there a "method" I can use to call the controller name and its method and that "method" returns the url for that one? Something like this:

```
build_site_url('product/details', array('my-product-url'));
```

where the first argument is the controller and its method (since only one controller exists for a url pattern), and the second argument is the array of url parts.

Comment: Don't put `^...$` in your routes -- the Router class will do that for you.

Comment: now I see it in `_parse_routes()` method. Thanks. I wish I could vote you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a feature called **reverse routing**. There is no such feature built into CodeIgniter at this time, and any library I could find was done in like 2010, so probably not the most up-to-date.

However, there are articles and pull requests out there relating to reverse routing, so if you are experienced enough, you should be able to put something together for your application.

Otherwise, your best bet may be to create helpers for your most common URLs (like your products). So you could do something like `echo product_url('my-product-name');`, and you would only need to adjust the URL in the helper function.

Comment: I didn't knew how to look on google after this. Thanks for the info. And building a helper is definitely a nice way of **reverse routing**. This way I will have the urls in only two files. But how do you replace regex urls? With regex, as the internet suggests, I will end up in the same spot where I was when I first asked my question.

Comment: That's kind of a lengthy explanation for a comment on SO. Essentially a reverse routing feature has a distinctive "id" for each route/destination, so you can specify what link should be generated. That ID can then accept X number of parameters for things like wild-card routes. I know it's kind of vague, but check out some existing solutions (for CI or other frameworks) and you should get an idea.

Comment: I have an idea about this, I actually build a reverse routing on a framework (not codeigniter), but had a few flaws. Basically, I assume that the user does not make mistakes in writing the url regexes (eg. in routes.php) and I just get the parenthesis and replace them from an array. The first key from array replaces the first set of parentheses. And it was not regex, it was using `strpos` and `str_replace`. I was assuming that codeigniter community had already a library, helper, etc.

Comment: That's essentially what you'd end up creating, yeah. Just use an array of parameters to fill in the wildcard spots in the route. And no, there's nothing in CI to aid in that process. `strpos` and `str_replace` or similar methods would be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly that you desired, but you can override controller behaviour using `_remap()` function;

look: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

e.g.

```
public function _remap($method){
   if ($method == 'product/details') {
     ///do what you want to do
   }
```

Comment: What I want: instead of calling the **site_url** function with the actual url, I want to call a **function** (or helper) with the **controller/method** as argument, and it will return the actual url.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a default lookup function in the product controller (described in the [CI Routing docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html); look at the examples).

```
$route['product/(:any)'] = "catalog/product_lookup";
```

> A URL with "product" as the first segment, and anything in the second
>   will be remapped to the "catalog" class and the "product_lookup"
>   method.

Or you could use database driven routes.
Add the table product_slugs to your MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_slugs` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `slug` varchar(192) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `slug` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Replace the code in application/config/routes.php with the one below:

```
$route[ 'default_controller' ]  = 'main';
$route[ '404_override' ]        = 'error404';

require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( 'product_slugs' );
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row )
{
    $route[ $row->slug ] = 'product/detail/$1;
}
```

All you would have to do then is to create a record when you create a product entry and you're done:

```
INSERT INTO `product_slugs` (`slug`) VALUES ('name-of-the-product');
```

Comment: You misunderstood me, because I have a problem with explaining things :). Please read @Charlie's first answer.

Comment: And I hope you didn't do that on a website. In routes there is a regex match for each route (method called **_parse_routes**). Regexes are slow. Imagine you would have 10000 products in your store, and you would ask for the last one...